# how to get android textsize settings in java (min, max, selected)

Tags: java, android, settings, text-size

for my app I want to give the user the possibility to adjust the textsize for TextView items in a recycler view (by pinch zoom or SeekBar). Default should be the textsize selected in the system settings. The minimum value should be the "very small" and the maximum value the "huge" value from the system settings.
I found some hints to use `Settings.System.getFloat(context`, `Settings.System.FONT_SCALE`) or `TextView.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Large)`, but I do not get the desired result by calling `TextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, value).`
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Dirk

Comment: Did you tried `TextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, value)`  ?

Comment: @sunnil sunny - yes, thanks, but it does not really answer my question. To get the current textsize I create a     `TextView`     object (without adding it to a layout) and call its     `getTextSize()`    method. I thought there will be a more elegant way and additionally: how to get the min and max values according to the system settings dialog?

Comment: I think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411099/how-to-get-default-text-size-from-textview-on-widget.

Comment: well, at least it seams that     `textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textView.getTextSize())`     does not change the textsize. That's ok. But is there no way to get the value from the system settings, as well as XS and XL 'limits'?

Answer (score 0):

May be it's because you are not converting "value" to the correct unit.Try this

```
  int size = ((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, value ,getResources().getDisplayMetrics())
```

Here your value is changed to correct unit in SP

```
TextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size)
```